# Powershell script to add multiple remote address to firewall rules

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will loop through local firewall rules and update the remote address table.

Here is what I have so far, it does not work. Should be simple, so not sure whats going on. The script runs without error, but does not actually update anything.

```
$name = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "*Desktop*" |ft   -HideTableHeaders Displayname
$ips = "192.168.1.150, 192.168.1.151"
foreach ($r in $name)
{
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $r -RemoteAddress $ips 
}
```

The $name variable passes in the rules I want to alter by name, the $ips variable passes in the IP addresses I want.

Does this script look right?

**Updated**

With the help of @Kev, whose comments/answers dissappeared for some reason, this is the working script....

```
$name = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "*Backup*" 
#$ips = @("192.168.1.150", "192.168.1.151")
foreach ($r in $name)
{
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $r.DisplayName -RemoteAddress $ips 
}
```

My only other question, is why is it $r.DisplayName?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `-RemoteAddress` parameter takes a string array, so you should change:

```
$ips = "192.168.1.150, 192.168.1.151"
```

to:

```
$ips = @("192.168.1.150", "192.168.1.151")
```

**Updated:**

Per your comment below, you don't need to pipe the result of `Get-NetFirewallRule` into `ft` or `Format-Table`. Do this instead:

```
$name = Get-NetFirewallrule -DisplayName "*Desktop*"

$ips = @("1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2")

foreach($r in $name)
{
    Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $r.DisplayName -RemoteAddress $ips
}
```

What you're doing is iterating the array of firewall objects directly which is slightly more efficient.

**Adding an IP address to an existing range of IPs in a rule:**

If you already have a rule which has been assigned one or more IP's, you can append additional IP's by doing:

```
$ips = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MyRule" | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter ).RemoteAddress
$ips += "192.168.1.123"
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MyRule" -RemoteAddress $ips
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Now I get......                                       Set-NetFirewallRule : No MSFT_NetFirewallRule objects found with property 'DisplayName' equal to
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.

Comment: @Nov2009 - apologies....should not come home from pub and play on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I learned from your example. The first time ever using Powershell ISE. And I was able to update the ips. I like to handcode, so I wrote everything out. No mistakes, worked straight away. Thanks, Anti-Santa... Wayne

Comment: @WayneBarron - you're welcome, glad this helped you out :)

Comment: And how to add IP list to an **existing** IPs in the rule?

Comment: Cool! Thanks. If I wanna pass not single IP but IP array, should I pass them comma-separated or like a string array from the beginning of your post: `$ips = @("192.168.1.150", "192.168.1.151")` ?

Comment: `$ips = @((Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MyRule" | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter ).RemoteAddress)` to make it work even if the existing list of IPs contains 1 entry. Otherwise $ips is a string and += does a string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

Combining the above answers, this is what I ended up using - this ADDS an ARRAY of IPs to the existing IPs in the rule:

```
$ips = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "MyRule" | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter ).RemoteAddress
$newips = @("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2")
$add = $ips + $newips
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "My Rule" -RemoteAddress $add
```

Answer (score 4):

in case you need to remove duplicate items and also sort the ips you can do this

```
$newips =@("1.2.3.4","5.3.4.5","4.2.3.5")
$ips  = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Attacker" | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter ).RemoteAddress
$ipconcat = $ips + $newips
$ipconcat = $ipconcat | select -Unique | sort
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Attacker" -RemoteAddress $ipconcat
```

Answer (score 0):

new version guy

```
$newips =("6.6.6.1", "6.6.6.1", "6.6.6")
$ips  = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Test-Rule" | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter ).RemoteAddress
if ($ips -notcontains 'Any'){
$ipconcat =  $newips + $ips}
else {$ipconcat = $newips}
$ipconcat = $ipconcat | select -Unique | sort
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Test-Rule" -RemoteAddress $ipconcat
```

Comment: ignore any in the rule and use sort

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).