# Group a list containing duplicate values

Tags: powershell

I have a list of Servers and ip-addresses what i need to create a new firewall rule for.

```
ServerName   IP
Server1  192.168.1.1
Server1  192.168.1.2
Server2  10.10.10.10
Server2  10.100.10.10
Server2  192.168.1.3
Server3  192.168.3.3
```

If I loop the servername it will create a new rule for every entry, is there a way so sort the group like
`Server 1 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2` and then loop each IP and add to the rule?

Comment: Is this _list of Servers_ in a CSV file perhaps? If not, what format does it have? A Hashtable of array of PSObjects maybe?

Comment: Its a System.Array

Answer (score 0):

If your list is an array of **objects**, something like this:

```
$list = [PsCustomObject]@{'ServerName' = 'Server1'; 'IP' = '192.168.1.1'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'ServerName' = 'Server1'; 'IP' = '192.168.1.2'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'ServerName' = 'Server2'; 'IP' = '10.10.10.10'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'ServerName' = 'Server2'; 'IP' = '10.100.10.10'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'ServerName' = 'Server2'; 'IP' = '192.168.1.3'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'ServerName' = 'Server3'; 'IP' = '192.168.3.3'}
```

then simply use the `Group-Object` and loop over

```
$list | Group-Object ServerName | ForEach-Object {
    # loop over the IP's in the server Group
    foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        # add the rule. For Demo just output something
        Write-Host "Adding rule for '$($item.ServerName)' on IP: $($item.IP)"
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Adding rule for 'Server1' on IP: 192.168.1.1
Adding rule for 'Server1' on IP: 192.168.1.2
Adding rule for 'Server2' on IP: 10.10.10.10
Adding rule for 'Server2' on IP: 10.100.10.10
Adding rule for 'Server2' on IP: 192.168.1.3
Adding rule for 'Server3' on IP: 192.168.3.3
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Only problem is that it creates a new rules for each IP. I guess that needs to be modified like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366963/powershell-script-to-add-multiple-remote-address-to-firewall-rules and "Adding an IP address to an existing range of IPs in a rule"